# Twitter Bootstrap Tabs: How to jump to anchor?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I would like the page to jump to the "tabreveal" ID when a View details button is clicked. What JS would I need to make this happen? Code is as follows:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3 box1">
      <h2>Web</h2>
       <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#web" data-toggle="tab">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 box2">
      <h2>Video</h2>
       <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#video" data-toggle="tab">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="span3 box3">
      <h2>Print</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#print" data-toggle="tab">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-content" id="tabreveal">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="web">2</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="video">3</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="print">4</div>
  </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any replies!

Comment: Add the link to the page in your post it will help people a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Tab Data API uses `preventDefault()`, which is why the browser doesn't scroll to the panes.  ([See source code.](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/v2.1.0/js/bootstrap-tab.js#L130))

The simplest thing to do would probably be to disable the event listener defined in Tab code, and then make your own without the call to `preventDefault()`.

Something like:

```
// disable old listener
$('body').off('click.tab.data-api')

// attach new listener
$('body').on('click.scrolling-tabs', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
  //e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

If you only wanted certain tabs to trigger a browser scroll, you could add some conditional statements in here to control whether or not `preventDefault()` is called.

Finally, make sure these overrides run *after* the tab plugin has been loaded.

---

### Viewport Conditional

If you want to check the viewport and decide whether to scroll based on its width, you could try:

```
$('body').on('click.scrolling-tabs', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
  $(window).width() > 767 && e.preventDefault()
  $(this).tab('show')
})
```

In Bootstrap, **767 px** is considered the upper limit of a "phone" viewport, but you can use whatever value you'd like.

Comment: Simply commenting out e.preventDefault() gave the desired result. Thank you! Now that I think about this more, would it be possible to create a conditional statement based on the devices' screen size? I wanted the ability to scroll to the anchor due to the way the site responds to smartphone screens. It doesn't make as much sense to do it on a desktop or tablet. If not, no worries.

Comment: @toddlikesdesign Glad to help. I've updated my answer to give an example of re-enabling the scrolling only for *phone-sized* viewports. If you found the answer helpful, please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Thank you again for your help. I learned something in all of this. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this action without any JavaScript code, all you need to do is to add anchor names in the right place, for example:

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tabreveal">
    <a name="web"></a><div class="tab-pane" id="web">2</div>
    <a name="video"></a><div class="tab-pane" id="video">3</div>
    <a name="print"></a><div class="tab-pane" id="print">4</div>
</div>
```

after adding the anchors, your links (`#web`, `#video`, `#print`) will jump to the right place.

Comment: Thank you for the tip but I tried that already with no luck which is why I'm assuming some JS needs to be involved. Check out http://mobilityhosting.com/html5testsite/

Comment: -1 There is no need to use anchors with `name` attributes; `id`'s work fine in all modern browsers, and the OP already has in the example what would otherwise be valid HTML to trigger browser scrolling. The issue is JS and Twitter Bootstrap, as were properly tagged in the OP.

Comment: +1. This answer is useful. Despite not responding directly to the exact specifics in the question, this answer provided an alternative that many newer developers many not even be aware about. TIMTOWTDI, newer doesn't imply better, and nothing wrong with knowing more.